# How to set an initial auto_increment value using doctrine2

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I use the doctrine2 mapper to generate my innoDB (mysql) database.
How to set the initial value of my auto_incremented id using the php annotations?

This is how I modelled the id of my entity type at the moment.

```
/**
 * @var integer $_id
 *
 * @Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @Id
 * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $_id;
```

I found the following code in the documentation but it looks as if it would use a separate table to generate the ids.

```
/**
 * @Id
 * @GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
 * @Column(type="integer")
 * @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="tablename_seq", initialValue=1, allocationSize=100)
 */
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the complete code example for setting the auto_increment in doctrine 2 in MySQL:

```
$connection = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
$connection->prepare('ALTER TABLE my_table AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;')->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set strategy="NONE" and set the last ID in a @prepersist function. More easy would be to just add a "ALTER TABLE something AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;" in a DataFixture or DB migration. It's not portable SQL but it does the job without adding complexity in your Entity.

Comment: how would you set the id in the prepersist function?

Comment: Get the highest +1 in the prepersist, but do it with the eventmanager

Comment: what about race conditions? I think following your advice it must be done with a transaction, and what if many entities are created in one go (e.g. in the install script) I think than you will get issues won't you?

Comment: well, my preferred solution would be to do put this in a DB migration or a fixture

Comment: I use fixtures in my Symfony2 project. You can read all about it here http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html I also did a Zend Framework project that used doctrine migrations, you can find more about that here http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/migrations/2.0/docs/reference/managing-migrations/en

Answer (score 1):

not really clear from documentation, but sources says ...

```
doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Platforms/MySqlPlatform.php:        if (isset($options['auto_increment'])) {
doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Platforms/MySqlPlatform.php:            $tableOptions[] = sprintf('AUTO_INCREMENT = %s', $options['auto_increment']);
```

so for mysql works as option for @table annotation

```
* @ORM\Table(name="xxx", options={"auto_increment": 100})
```

Comment: [You previously posted this exact same answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31867992/doctrine-auto-increment-starting-value-orm-generatedvalue/45599115#45599115). Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Pick the best question and post one good answer there, and then flag to close the other question(s) as duplicates. If the questions are not duplicates, you must [*tailor your answers specifically to each question*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/311792).