# Doctrine Auto Increment Starting Value @ORM\GeneratedValue

Tags: php, sql, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

How can I set the starting value for an Auto Incremented id using annotations ?

I want it to start at 250000

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
protected $id;
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
 * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="id", initialValue=250000)
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
 protected $id;
```

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html

Comment: correct me if I am wrong but this won't on MySql right? As MySql doesn't have sequence it has AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: Doctrine abstracts that all away and makes it work according to the DBMS choosen. If the underlying DBMS doesn't support sequence or auto increment, then doctrine will handle incrementing internally

Comment: [Currently - 2.5.4](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifier-generation-strategies), Sequences are supported only by Oracle, PostgreSql and SQL Anywhere.

Answer (score 7):

On MySQL platform, I write that (`@ORM\Table(options={"auto_increment": 12345})`) to add "AUTO_INCREMENT = 12345" to the SQL creation table. I didn't use `@ORM\SequenceGenerator`:

```
/*
 * @ORM\Table(options={"auto_increment": 12345})
 */
class MyEntity {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    // Others properties
}
```

And in the migration file:

```
    $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE my_entity (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, ...) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 12345');
```

Comment: Thanks, this is probably the best solution if you use MySQL. It actually uses the database to handle incrementing, unlike the SequenceGenerator solution, and you don't have to make any edits to the generated migration file, Doctrine sets the proper AUTO_INCREMENT value from the entity annotation.

Comment: Would the option in the `Table` attribute also be necessary if the database migration is handled by a completely different component in our business architecture which uses Flyway for DB migration?

Answer (score 6):

Don't know this answer is useful to users or not.
But for me its giving required result (for docrtine with mysql)
I had used auto increment id as normally used,

```
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;
```

First time you run command to update than table will create.
Than you should manually run below command to set custom initial auto increment id

```
ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT=1001;
```

Again on running schema it will not update auto increment which is manually set.
And thats it!! Its the desired result.